# Error: Missing Operator in Query Expression VBA

Tags: sql, excel, vba

I'm writing VBA to loop through excel files and upload the data to an access crime db.

My template sql statement is:

```vb
sql = "insert into crimedata(reportYear, state, school, campus, dataLabel, dataValue)" & _ 
      "values(<reportYear>, <state>, <school>, <campus>, <dataLabel>, <dataValue>);"
```

My logic for building the query and executing it are as follows:

```vb
sql = Replace(sql, "<dataValue>", s.Cells(i, c).value)
sql = Replace(sql, "<reportYear>", Year)
sql = Replace(sql, "<state>", State)
sql = Replace(sql, "<school>", s.Cells(i, 1).value)
    If s.Cells(i, 2).value = "" Then
       sql = Replace(sql, "<campus>", "null")
    Else
       sql = Replace(sql, "<campus>", s.Cells(i, 2).value)
    End If
sql = Replace(sql, "<dataLabel>", s.Cells(5, c).value)
cn.Execute sql
```

When I remove `cn.Execute sql` and `Debug.Print sql` after each loop I get statements like these:

```sql
insert into crimedata(reportYear, state, school, campus, dataLabel, dataValue)values(2011, ALASKA, University of Alaska, Fairbanks, Larceny, 64);
    
insert into crimedata(reportYear, state, school, campus, dataLabel, dataValue)values(2011, ALASKA, University of Alaska, Fairbanks, Autotheft, 3);
```

However, when I add `cn.Execute sql` to execute the query, I get the following error:

> Run-time error '-2147217900 (80040e14)': Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'University of Alaska'
>
> [image: screenshot]

I'm unsure what I'm missing syntax wise?

Answer (score 0):

Your values need to be in quotes like below if they are text:

```
values(2011, 'ALASKA', 'University of Alaska', 'Fairbanks', 'Larceny', 64)
```

so adjust here:

```vb
sql = "INSERT INTO crimedata (reportYear, state, school, campus, dataLabel, dataValue)" & _ 
      "VALUES (<reportYear>, '<state>', '<school>', '<campus>', '<dataLabel>', <dataValue>);"
```

If your fields `reportYear` and `dataValue` defined as text fields too, then wrap them into quotes `''` too, if they are defined as number fields then don't.